# CURLOPT_NOPROXY does not affect in PHP

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have http_proxy settings in my /etc/environment on my Ubuntu machine. I have defined CURLOPT_NOPROXY as 10177 and then do

```
$curl = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOPROXY, '127.0.0.1'); // or '*'
// ... set others params and options ...
curl_exec($curl);
```

But this does not affect my script and I receive proxy error message instead of WebDriver response. At the same time using `curl --noproxy 127.0.0.1 http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub` from command line works well.

Additional env info:

```
curl --version
curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) 
libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 
libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3 
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

PHP version is 5.3.10.

How can I set up noproxy option from my PHP script?

**UPDATED:** Looks like it should work https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53543 in PHP.

Comment: I had this issue when cUrl to non ssl endpoints from localhost

Comment: Sidenote as of 2019: `CURLOPT_NOPROXY` has been [removed from the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) and when using `CURLOPT_NOPROXY` in PHP 5.5 I  get `Segmentation fault` without further detail.

Answer (score 11):

It happened with me so i set the proxy to empty string and it worked

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
```

Comment: In this case it is used system proxy that not corresponded.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with curl using a proxy only in PHP curl calls. I eventually found that SUSE specifically SLES 11 had some proxy values set. Changing those proxy values fixed issues in linux but I had to restart the entire server not just apache for the changes to take affect in PHP. I used YAST to change the proxy values on the server.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP's Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), you should set CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL to false:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, false);
```

Comment: Such a boolean flag would have been more elegant, unfortunately, that answer did not work for me, however @user3107408's answer did.