# PHP cURL request primary_ip is different than cURL url

Tags: php, linux, curl

When making a curl request through PHP, curl gets "couldn't connect to host". When I dump the curl info the `primary_ip` is not the ip of the requested server.

```
$soapURL ="www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $soapURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$header[] = "SOAPAction: ". "";
$header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$header[] = "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump($info);
```

This works fine on my test server but not on production. On the production server this is the response I get:

> Array
>
> 7
>
> couldn't connect to host
> array(23) { ["url"]=> string(21) "http://www.google.com" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(2.7E-5) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(10) "10.1.99.87" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } }

`primary_ip => 10.1.99.87` is my local machine (not running this PHP code). It seems like curl is trying to connect to my local machine instead of the url I gave it. I tried this from another computer and the IP stayed as my machine, it didn't change to that of the new machine.

When I use the test server I get:

> Array
>
> 0
>
> array(23) { ["url"]=> string(21) "http://www.google.com" ["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8" ["http_code"]=> int(405) ["header_size"]=> int(260) ["request_size"]=> int(948) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.120098) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.029716) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.073289) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.073292) ["size_upload"]=> float(815) ["size_download"]=> float(1453) ["speed_download"]=> float(12098) ["speed_upload"]=> float(6786) ["download_content_length"]=> float(1453) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(0) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.119125) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(14) "74.125.198.106" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } }

Which is what is supposed to happen.

There used to be Linux environment variables set for http_proxy which was set to my machine that I set to be empty. Also making a curl call from the command line works fine. It's just any curl call that php tries to make that fails.

[Similar Problem with workaround solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653805/curlopt-noproxy-does-not-affect-in-php)

Comment: proxy_http variable exists inside of phpinfo() but is not set in any .ini file. I'm not sure where else to look. I've tried running a grep command on the ip that is set as the proxy but my session expires before it can finish

Answer (score 0):

SUSE specifically SLES 11 has some proxy settings you can access in the directory or via YAST like I did. Changing these settings and enabling or disabling the proxy would affect calls made via the command line in Linux but did not affect curl calls made via PHP. Restarting Apache also didn't change anything. PHP still had environmental variables set for the http_proxy. Restarting the entire server(init 6) after I removed all the proxy settings via YAST fixed the proxy problem for me. Simply disabling the proxy wasn't enough. I had to clear out the proxy setting in yast.