# What is equivalent for "curl -v --noproxy localhost" in php?

Tags: php, curl

I cannot curl localhost from php, but any other external host works fine.

From cmd I've tried "curl localhost" - it didn't work too, but ingnoring proxy for localhost "curl -v --noproxy localhost" - works.

What is equivalent for this in php?

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting the proxy to an empty string:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
```

Another possibility is to add a proxy exception to your env var "no_proxy", but i'm not 100% sure if it affects PHP:

```
set no_proxy=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');` worked for me, thanks.

Comment: I also have similar issue. However, the answer provided here did not work for me. Strange thing is, I've a php script that returns expected value. However, when I'm calling it from inside of PHP Framework (CakePHP 2.0), it returns with 503 error, even when I'm not setting any proxy, or setting a proxy with empty string. I'll try to find out why.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same issue. I was working in a company which sits behind a proxy, so we need to add proxy to curl calls when making outbound calls. However, for locally hosted sites, the curl call was failing.

What worked for me is this one ([CURLOPT_NOPROXY does not affect in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653805/curlopt-noproxy-does-not-affect-in-php)[It)'s the update part of the question where a link was provided):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOPROXY, 'your-sitename-on-localhost');
```

This will skip proxy when it matches a sitename in the URL.

Previously I was receiving 503, and now it is returning the correct 200 status code for the site on my localhost.

Comment: I've to add more to this, as there is not much documentation on this. Do not try to add this option as `curl_setopt_array()`, but that did not work. This has to be added after the `curl_init()` call, and before `curl_exec()` using `curl_setopt()` method only. I still don't know why it's like that, but will update it here if I find an answer.